# Swift Foundation Calendar nextDate() produces strange results

Tags: swift, calendar, foundation

Here's what I think is a bug that I reported to Apple last June (bug no. 41023217) but received no reply. Any insights welcome.

Summary:

Scanning back and forward for dates that match month produces weird results. Forward scans do not seem to handle daylight savings correctly. Backward scans produce results that sometimes seem simply wrong.

Steps to Reproduce:

Launch swift REPL in terminal and run this code:

```swift
import Foundation
var now = Date()
var cal = Calendar.current
var comp = DateComponents()
print("Scanning forward")
for monthNo in 1...12 {
    comp.setValue(monthNo, for: .month)
    let nextDate = cal.nextDate(after: now, matching: comp, matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .forward)
    print("Month: ", monthNo, ", next date: ", nextDate)
}
print("Scanning backward")
for monthNo in 1...12 {
    comp.setValue(monthNo, for: .month)
    let nextDate = cal.nextDate(after: now, matching: comp, matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .backward)
    print("Month: ", monthNo, ", next date: ", nextDate)
}
```

Expected Results:

Next date with corresponding month value for forward search.
Most recent date with corresponding month value for backward search (or at least start of most recent range with corresponding month value).

Actual Results:

```
Scanning forward
Month:  1 , next date:  Optional(2020-01-01 00:00:00 +0000)
Month:  2 , next date:  Optional(2020-02-01 00:00:00 +0000)
Month:  3 , next date:  Optional(2019-03-01 00:00:00 +0000)
Month:  4 , next date:  Optional(2019-03-31 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  5 , next date:  Optional(2019-04-30 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  6 , next date:  Optional(2019-05-31 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  7 , next date:  Optional(2019-06-30 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  8 , next date:  Optional(2019-07-31 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  9 , next date:  Optional(2019-08-31 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  10 , next date:  Optional(2019-09-30 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  11 , next date:  Optional(2019-11-01 00:00:00 +0000)
Month:  12 , next date:  Optional(2019-12-01 00:00:00 +0000)
Scanning backward
Month:  1 , next date:  Optional(2019-01-05 00:00:00 +0000)
Month:  2 , next date:  Optional(2018-02-01 01:00:00 +0000)
Month:  3 , next date:  Optional(2018-03-02 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  4 , next date:  Optional(2018-03-31 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  5 , next date:  Optional(2018-05-02 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  6 , next date:  Optional(2018-05-31 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  7 , next date:  Optional(2018-07-01 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  8 , next date:  Optional(2018-08-31 22:00:00 +0000)
Month:  9 , next date:  Optional(1970-08-31 23:00:00 +0000)
Month:  10 , next date:  Optional(2018-10-03 00:00:00 +0000)
Month:  11 , next date:  Optional(2018-11-01 00:00:00 +0000)
Month:  12 , next date:  Optional(2018-12-31 23:59:59 +0000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misuse of your matching policies and repeated time policies..

But if you want your **expected** **result** with `Calendar` you can **use** the **following code**:

```
// Import Foundation to use 'Calendar' and 'Date' classes and structures  
import Foundation

/// Setting the current user calendar
let cal = Calendar.autoupdatingCurrent

/// Saving the current date
let now = Date()

print("Forward scanning... ->")
for i in 1...12 {
    /// Storing result
    let date = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: i, to: now)
    // Print result
    print("Mounth: \(i), date: \(date!.debugDescription)")
}

print("\nBackward scanning... ->")
for i in 1...12 {
    /// Storing result << please take note of the second argument>>>
    let date = cal.date(byAdding: .month, value: -i, to: now)
    // Print result
    print("Mounth: \(i), date: \(date!.debugDescription)")
}
```

When you use `date(byAdding: 'Calendar.Component', value: 'Int', to: 'Date')`, the calendar search by offsets of literal month

Answer (score 0):

You can further qualify `DateComponents` and I believe you get the values you’re looking for:

```
var comp = DateComponents(calendar: cal, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)
```

Thus:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .short
formatter.timeStyle = .short

let now = Date()
let calendar = Calendar.current
var components = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, day: 1, hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)

print("Scanning forward")
for monthNo in 1...12 {
    components.setValue(monthNo, for: .month)
    let nextDate = calendar.nextDate(after: now, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .forward)
    print("Month: ", monthNo, ", next date: ", formatter.string(from: nextDate!))
}

print("Scanning backward")
for monthNo in 1...12 {
    components.setValue(monthNo, for: .month)
    let nextDate = calendar.nextDate(after: now, matching: components, matchingPolicy: .strict, repeatedTimePolicy: .first, direction: .backward)
    print("Month: ", monthNo, ", next date: ", formatter.string(from: nextDate!))
}
```

Produces:

> Scanning forward 
>   Month:  1 , next date:  1/1/20, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  2 , next date:  2/1/20, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  3 , next date:  3/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  4 , next date:  4/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  5 , next date:  5/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  6 , next date:  6/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  7 , next date:  7/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  8 , next date:  8/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  9 , next date:  9/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  10 , next date:  10/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  11 , next date:  11/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  12 , next date:  12/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Scanning backward  
>   Month:  1 , next date:  1/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  2 , next date:  2/1/19, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  3 , next date:  3/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  4 , next date:  4/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  5 , next date:  5/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  6 , next date:  6/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  7 , next date:  7/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  8 , next date:  8/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  9 , next date:  9/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  10 , next date:  10/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  11 , next date:  11/1/18, 12:00 AM 
>   Month:  12 , next date:  12/1/18, 12:00 AM